# Face pose estimation using Lucas and POSIT

Tags: opencv

I am working on an AR project where i have to find how much angle a face has been rotated. For this i followed below steps

Step 1: Mark some points on the face.

Step 2: Track these points using Luckas Kanade optical flow algorithm

Step 3: Define a 3D model corresponding to the points marked above.

Step 4: Provide the output points from LK mapped to image points and above 3D model to POSIT for finding the pose estimation and find the rotation matrix

Step 5: Derive the eular angle using opencv function cvRodrigues2

Now coming to my question, this implentation shows different behavior in different faces. i.e. On some faces as the face turns towards left i am getting -ve   angle magnitude and towards right i am getting +ve angle magnitude and on some faces vice versa.

Can someone help me in analyzing why this behavior is shown?

Comment: Please leave us with code so that we can help....